# TypeError: 'open' called on an object that does not implement interface Window

Tags: events, kendo-ui, mozilla

This is a kendo DropDownList. I want to show an alert when it is opened.

```
@(Html.Kendo()
.DropDownList()
.Name("DropdownList")
.BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = "Drop Down" },
 new SelectListItem() { Text = "Office" } })
.Events(e=>e.Open("open")))
```

// Following is the simple script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function open(e) {
    alert("Hello");
}
</script>
```

This gives me the error "**TypeError: 'open' called on an object that does not implement interface Window."** 
I am getting this error in Mozilla 29.0.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Got the solution. jQuery was included twice.